# Axios Interceptors Get Request on Response Error

Tags: axios

When using axios.interceptors.response, I want to log the request when there is an error.

```
function setupInterceptors(instance: AxiosInstance): AxiosInstance {
  instance.interceptors.request.use(requestInjectBearerToken);
  instance.interceptors.response.use(responseRetrieveData, function (error) {
    // on error, let's send the error to Sentry
    Sentry.captureException(error, (scope) => {
      scope.setContext("context", error);
      return scope;
    });

    return Promise.reject(error);
  });

  return instance;
}
```

Currently, when just capturing error, the request is not being captured, just the error response.

Is there a way to capture the request but only on response error?

Cheers

Expecting request on response error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AxiosInterceptorManager.use()` function accepts two parameters... `onFullfilled` and `onRejected`.

If you're only interested in errors, you only need to supply the 2nd `onRejected` handler (passing `null` for the 1st).

The request is available in the `error.config` property (see [Handling Errors](https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors))

```js
axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(null, (error) => {
  console.warn(error.config); // log the request details
  return Promise.reject(error); // ensure the promise chain keeps failing
});
```

Comment: Hi Phil,
Thanks for that but to answer my question, what I am after is capturing the request when there is an error. eg. I want to know what the request was that led to the onRejected handler.

Comment: @PratikDhody right. I've update my answer; the request is available in `error.config`